# Excel Vba not opening correct workbooks?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

My excel code was able to iterate through every workbook in a specified folder, although it does so in an eternal loop. (Which i stop using the keyboard  interrupt)

Vba based off this: http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/2007-filesearch-alternative.htm

Now, after switching PCs, the code has gone haywire. The vba is still the same but instead of opening workbooks in the specified folder, its opening workbooks in the folder one folder before it.

E.g Vba is in S:\Excel\Test
It will open books in  S:\Excel 
Instead of a specified location in C. Drive S is a networked drive

Not only that, while it used to iterate through EVERY file, it now just keeps resetting and opening the first file again and again

Using Excel 2007

Comment: Moving the workbook over to C drive seems to help but it keeps grabbing the first  file over and over again

Comment: "My excel code" - which you don't seem to want to share ? It's difficult to make any suggestions without it.

Comment: Oh hey sry, forgot to include the link. Its relatively the same as the links one. And i meant it as the code im running, as opposed to my personally written code

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: Hi trimax, really sorry, im not able to do so cos my code is 100s of lines long and not on a PC with  internet connection unfortunately.

Comment: So you've got a problem with code some 100's of lines long, you can't or won't distill it down to the few lines that are causing you a problem and post these so that people who might actually try and help you can see the specifics of your problem and, by doing so, help you find a solution. Being "relatively the same as the links one" isn't actually the same code that is causing you the problem. Why bother posting in the first place, as you can't/won't provide appropriate details of your problem?

Comment: I cant provide the code because  its on a PC without internet connection, and i was hoping  that people experiencing the same issue (Calling macros from networked drives from different PCs) would have a solution, especially seeing as though i have helped others without looking at their codes before, it could be a matter of just identifying the possible pitfalls in the situation

Comment: You're not specifying the correct path when you open the workbooks. Simple as that.

Comment: Unfortunately thats not the case cos shifting the location of the workbook, without reapecifying the path seems to solve the problem

Comment: Solved the issue, must change drive that excel looks at using ChDrive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys the answer is simple. Because im using a networked drive, one should refer to the drive on which the workbook is stored. Adding one line to the top above ChDir solves this

ChDrive (Left (ThisWorkbook.Path, 2))

Im also glad to report that this question did not require me posting my code as well.